# Using an already created model for scoring a new data set in R

Tags: r, model, predict

I have built a linear regression i R. Now I wanna store the model and use it for scoring a new data set once a week.

Someone that can help me with how to?

How to save the model and how to import it and use it on an new dataset.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reusing a Model Built in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118074/reusing-a-model-built-in-r)

Answer (score 7):

You can save the model in a file and load it when you need it.

For example, you might have a line like this to train your model:

```
the_model <- glm(my_formula, family=binomial(link='logit'),data=training_set)
```

This model can be saved with:

```
save(file="modelfile",the_model) #the name of the file is of course arbitrary
```

Later, assuming that the file is in the working directory, you can reuse that model by first loading it with

```
load(file="modelfile")
```

The model can then be applied to a (new) data set `test_set` like, e.g.,

```
test_set$pred <- predict(the_model, newdata=test_set, type='response')
```

Note that the name, in this case `the_model` should not be assigned to a variable (don't use something like `the_model <- load("modelfile")`). The model with its name becomes available with the `load()` function. Also, the model remains the same as it was before. The new observations are not changing the coefficients or anything in the model - the "old" model is applied to make predictions on new data.

If, however, you have an additional labeled set and you want to train / improve the model on the basis of these new observations, you can follow the suggestions in the answer by @David.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `update` function:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100),
                  y = rnorm(100, 0.01))

lmobj <- lm(y~x, dat)

coef(lmobj)
# (Intercept)            x 
# -0.027692614 -0.001060386

dat2 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10),
                   y = rnorm(10, 0.01))

lmobj2 <- update(lmobj, dat2)
coef(lmobj2)
# (Intercept)             y 
# 0.1088614395 -0.0009323697 

#--------------------------------
# to make things a bit more clear:
# lmobj2 is not the same as a new model such as the following
lmobj3 <- lm(y~x, dat2)
coef(lmobj3)
#(Intercept)           x 
#-0.02386837  0.06973995
```

Comment: I think this is helpful to change / adapt the model according to a new data set. However, the way I understood the OP the goal is to use the *same*, trained model on a different data set.