# How to share trained logistic models with others?

Tags: r, machine-learning, logistic-regression, rdata

I have 5 logistic models trained using the private data. I want them to be validated on another private data by another member. How do I share share the trained models such that they can be evaluated on another system running an arbitrary version of R and packages (i.e. as portably as possible)? I know about `.RData` files, but they don't solve the dependency or data dependency issue.

Edit:
Tried the [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118074/reusing-a-model-built-in-r) mentioned using `save`, `load` like below

```
save(Model1, file = "my_model1.test.rda")
model_diff <- load('my_model1.test.rda')
model_diff
[1] "Model1"
```

But the loaded model `model_diff` contained string `"Model1"` instead of the contents of it.

Comment: So http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118074/reusing-a-model-built-in-r is not sufficient?

Comment: Even better, `saveRDS()` and `readRDS()` allow you to name the variable: `prradep_model <- readRDS("my_awesome_model.rds")`

Comment: Roman, @m-dz thanks for the comments. I will look into these options and test them.

Comment: @ari-b-friedman Thanks for the edit to make it as clear as possible. Could you please help me in understanding - " but they don't solve the dependency or data dependency issue" ??

Comment: Back compatibility can be a hassle in every software. If you really want to have a fully reproducible environment, you'll have to figure out how to encapsulate a specific R version and specific packages. See this discussion for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24283171/virtual-environment-in-r

Comment: @RomanLuštrik The `save` function in the link mentioned in first comment did not work.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What precisely did it not work?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I have used the `save` function and tried to load the object for using the model but it didn't load the model.

Comment: What are the commands you use? Please add this information to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone looking for answer, models can be saved using `saveRDS()`

```
saveRDS(lm.model, 'my_model.rds')
```

and load them in different session using `readRDS()` function

```
Model_load <- readRDS('my_model.rds')
```

based on [m-dz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4272484/m-dz)'s answer.