# How to correctly `dput` a fitted linear model (by `lm`) to an ASCII file and recreate it later?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm

I want to persist a `lm` object to a file and reload it into another program.  I know I can do this by writing/reading a binary file via `saveRDS`/`readRDS`, but I'd like to have an ASCII file instead of a binary file.  At a more general level, I'd like to know why my idioms for reading in `dput` output in general is not behaving as I'd expect.

Below are examples of making a simple fit, and successful and unsuccessful recreations of the model:

```
dat_train <- data.frame(x=1:4, z=c(1, 2.1, 2.9, 4))
fit <- lm(z ~ x, dat_train)
rm(dat_train) # Just to make sure fit is not dependent upon `dat_train existence`

dat_score <- data.frame(x=c(1.5, 3.5))

## This works (of course)
predict(fit, dat_score)
#    1    2 
# 1.52 3.48
```

Saving to binary file works:

```
## http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118074/reusing-a-model-built-in-r
saveRDS(fit, "model.RDS")
fit2 <- readRDS("model.RDS")
predict(fit2, dat_score)
#    1    2 
# 1.52 3.48
```

So does this (`dput` it in the R session not to a file):

```
fit2 <- eval(dput(fit))
predict(fit2, dat_score)
#    1    2 
# 1.52 3.48
```

But if I persist file to disk, I cannot figure out how to get back into normal shape:

```
dput(fit, file = "model.R")
fit3 <- source("model.R")$value

# Error in is.data.frame(data): object 'dat_train' not found

predict(fit3, dat_score)
# Error in predict(fit3, dat_score): object 'fit3' not found
```

Trying to be explicit with the `eval` does not work either:

```
## http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068397/import-text-file-as-single-character-string
dput(fit, file="model.R")
fit4 <- eval(parse(text=paste(readLines("model.R"), collapse=" ")))

# Error in is.data.frame(data): object 'dat_train' not found

predict(fit4, dat_score)
# Error in predict(fit4, dat_score): object 'fit4' not found
```

In both cases above, I expect `fit3` and `fit4` to both work, but they don't recompile into a `lm` object that I can use with `predict()`.

Can anyone advise me on how I can persist a model to a file with a `structure(...)` ASCII-like structure, and then re-read it back in as a `lm` object I can use in `predict()`?  And why my current methods are not working?

Comment: I tried using to `dget` to reread the file but I am obtaining the error "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'z' not found."  The dput/dget combination should work but It does not appear to do so in this case.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Step 1:**

You need to control de-parsing options:

```
dput(fit, control = c("quoteExpressions", "showAttributes"), file = "model.R")
```

You can read more on all possible options in `?.deparseOpts`.

---

The "quoteExpressions" wraps all calls / expressions / languages with `quote`, so that they are not evaluated when you later re-parse it. Note:

- `source` is doing parsing;
- `call` field in your fitted "lm" object is a call:

  ```
  fit$call
  # lm(formula = z ~ x, data = dat_train)
  ```

So, without "quoteExpressions", R will try to evaluate `lm` call during parsing. And if we evaluate it, it is fitting a linear model, and R will aim to find `dat_train`, which will not exist in your new R session.

---

The "showAttributes" is another mandatory option, as "lm" object has class attributes. You certainly don't want to discard all class attributes and only export a plain "list" object, right? Moreover, many elements in a "lm" object, like `model` (the model frame), `qr` (the compact QR matrix) and `terms` (terms info), etc all have attributes. You want to keep them all.

---

If you don't set `control`, the default setting with:

```
control = c("keepNA", "keepInteger", "showAttributes")
```

will be used. As you can see, there is no "quoteExpressions", so you will get into trouble.

You can also specify "keepInteger" and "keepNA", but I don't see the need for "lm" object.

### ------

**Step 2:**

The above step will get `source` working correctly. You can recover your model:

```
fit1 <- source("model.R")$value
```

However, it is not yet ready for generic functions like `summary` and `predict` to work. Why?

The critical issue is the `terms` object in `fit1` is not really a "terms" object, but only a formula (*it is even not a formula, but only a "language" object without "formula" class!*). Just compare `fit$terms` and `fit1$terms`, and you will see the difference. Don't be surprised; we've set "quoteExpressions" earlier. While that is definitely helpful to prevent evaluation of `call`, it has side-effect for `terms`. So we need to reconstruct `terms` as best as we can.

Fortunately, it is sufficient to do:

```
fit1$terms <- terms.formula(fit1$terms)
```

Though this still does not recover all information in `fit$terms` (like variable classes are missing), it is readily a valid "terms" object.

Why is a "terms" object critical? Because all generic functions rely on it. You may not need to know more on this, as it is really technical, so I will stop here.

Once this is done, we can successfully use `predict` (and `summary`, too):

```
predict(fit1)  ## no `newdata` given, using model frame `fit1$model`
#   1    2    3    4 
#1.03 2.01 2.99 3.97 

predict(fit1, dat_score)  ## with `newdata`
#   1    2 
#1.52 3.48
```

### -------

**Conclusion remark:**

Although I have shown you how to get things work, I don't really recommend you doing this in general. An "lm" object will be pretty large when you fit a model to a large dataset, for example, `residuals`, `fitted.values` are long vectors, and `qr` and `model` are huge matrices / data frames. So think about this.

Answer (score 2):

**This is an important update!**

As mentioned in the previous answer, the most challenging bit is to recover `$terms` as best as we can. The suggested method using `terms.formula` works for OP's example, but not for the following with `bs()` and `poly()`:

```
dat <- data.frame(x1 = runif(20), x2 = runif(20), x3 = runif(20), y = rnorm(20))
library(splines)
fit <- lm(y ~ bs(x1, df = 3) + poly(x2, degree = 3) + x3, data = dat)
rm(dat)
```

If we follow the previous answer:

```
dput(fit, control = c("quoteExpressions", "showAttributes"), file = "model.R") 
fit1 <- source("model.R")$value
fit1$terms <- terms.formula(fit1$terms)
```

We will see that `summary.lm` and `anova.lm` work correctly, but not `predict.lm`:

```
predict(fit1, newdata = data.frame(x1 = 0.5, x2 = 0.5, x3 = 0.5))
```

> Error in bs(x1, df = 3) : could not find function "bs"

This is because `".Environment"` attribute of `$terms` is missing. We need

```
environment(fit1$terms) <- .GlobalEnv
```

Now run above `predict` again we see a different error:

> Error in poly(x2, degree = 3) :
>
> 'degree' must be less than number of unique points

This is because we are missing `"predvars"` attributes for safe / correct prediction of `bs()` and `poly()`.

A remedy is that we need to `dput` such special attribute **additionally**:

```
dput(attr(fit$terms, "predvars"), control = "quoteExpressions", file = "predvars.R")
```

then read and add it

```
attr(fit1$terms, "predvars") <- source("predvars.R")$value
```

Now running `predict` works correctly.

Note that `"dataClass"` attribute of `$terms` is also missing, but this does not seem to cause any problem for any generic functions.